# How to add a dependency from my local file system with Rebar3?

Tags: erlang, rebar, rebar3

I have two Erlang applications: single app `mylogger` and umbrella app `myapp`.

I want to include a current version of `mylogger` as a dependency to `myapp`.

Rebar3 only suggests to add deps from git like

```
{mylogger, {git, "https://github.com/someuser/mylogger", {branch, "master"}}}
```

or from hex.pm.

How to add my custom app from the file system with rebar3 structure?

Answer (score 4):

Use [checkouts dependencies](https://rebar3.org/docs/configuration/dependencies/#checkout-dependencies). If you add your application in the `_checkouts` folder it will do the following.

> Any application/plugin in _checkouts will take precedence over the
> same application if it is additionally listed in the rebar.config's
> deps, plugins or project_plugins

In the past there was an issue where the directory in `_checkouts` was used for the artifacts too, if I read the last release notes correctly, this was corrected already.